# Como utilizar correctamente las Cards de Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

He estado probando las cards de bootstrap; lo único que deseo hacer es poner 4 cards, 2 en una linea y otras 2 en la linea de abajo, eso ya lo logre, el problema esta en que si por ejemplo, la primera card tiene más contenido que las demás, el diseño se desfasa y queda un espacio vació.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que forma puedo lograrlo sin importar que una tarjeta tenga mayor contenido que la otra y la que debe estar abajo, se posicione en donde debe de estar?

Espero que me puedan ayudar y por favor, les agradecería mucho si me pudieran explicar lo que esta pasando, necesito aprender.

Dejo el codigo de la pag:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion A
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
          </p>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion B
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card padding-0">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion C
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion D
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deseas que estén alineadas como corresponde al sistema de grids de bootstrap o que aparezcan desalineadas pero sin espacio una de la otra?

Comment: Exacto, esa era la idea, ¿de que forma es posible lograrlo?.

Answer (score 2):

creo que la solución pasa por disponer el diseño en dos rows:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion A
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
          </p>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion B
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion C
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Subestacion D
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
          Ultima actualización: Hace 2 minutos
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podría ser una muy buena solución... ¿en caso de que necesitara que se quedaran completamente pegadas? por ejemplo, en la card de la derecha tiene un poco de espació, ¿seria muy complicado quitar ese espacio? Que las cards se posicionaran siempre por debajo una de otras.

Comment: Cuando dices pegadas ¿te refieres la fila superior con la inferior?

Comment: Así es. Lo siento por mi mala explicación.

Comment: En este caso no es posible, al estar cada una en una fila, si alguno de los elementos tiene más altura que el otro, la fila completa se desplaza hasta la altura del elemento más grande. De todas formas pensé que eso era lo que querías, ¿no?